# XCode: UNIX[Permission denied] when trying to download development certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6

I'm attempting to provision my iOS device for development with Xcode 4.6 by creating a signing certificate. I've tried following the instructions in Technical Note TN2250 https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html under "Provisioning Profile Refresh." However, when I hit "Refresh" and I log in using my Apple Developer account it seems like it tries to retrieve something "Downloading development certificates..." then dies abruptly with an "Error, could not import certificate. (UNIX[Permission denied])". I've been able to edit my OS X keychain just fine before, why is Xcode unable to add to it now?

Comment: Can you manually download the certificate from the provisioning portal and install it that way?

Comment: Nope, when I try to install the cert into my Keychain I get this error: An error occurred. Unable to import “iPhone Developer: David LastName (XXXXXXXXXXX)”.

Error: 100013

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: also getting the same error. Surprised there has been no answer for 3 years

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get here from some google search. I had similar issues with "UNIX[Permission denied]". It turned out that somehow I have messed up some folder permission but I could not figure out which one. I followed another advice:

1. Create new admin account on your Mac
2. Login to that account, copy your solution to home folder
3. Open Xcode and login with your apple id and download all certificates (in projects setting go to  signing and select checkbox "automatically manage signing")
4. Build your project - it should work now

This worked for me on Xcode 13.1 and macOS 11.6